# Configure WordPress to Use Responsive Image Rendering

Tags: php, images, html, responsive, google

We have a website that has custom built page templates. Each page template is fully responsive for mobile view.

We ran our site through Google's PageSpeed Insights tool.
The biggest problem we see is the size of the images, particularly on the homepage.
Each image is around 300 - 400 KB. We were under the impression this file size is acceptable, but maybe it's not.

A consulting company we use suggested we configure WP to use responsive image rendering for wp-content images.

I am confused since our page templates are fully responsive, and any image will inherit the responsive element on a page.
Can someone please help me understand what would need to be done to configure WordPress to use responsive image rendering for wp-content images?

Answer (score 0):

A high resolution image suitable for a big desktop screen is overhead on a mobile screen. The mobile device has to download the big image and then to scale it down to fit on the smaller screen. With responsive images the server offers the image in several sizes and the client browser selects the one that's closest in size. See the overview at the WordPress APIs handbook: [Responsive Images](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/responsive-images/).